# Tnet issues for R SNA

Tags: r, igraph, sna

I'm getting two unexpected errors for tnet functions in R. My edgelist:

```
Person    Event
1 a

2 b

3 c

edgelist <- as.matrix("file.csv")
edgelist_in_igraph <- graph.edgelist(edgelist)
edgelist_in_tnet <- as.tnet(edgeist_in_igraph)

cluster_coefficients <- clustering_local_tm(edgelist_in_tnet)

> error: "max not meaningful for factors"
```

And if I try to make it one mode:

```
onemode <- projecting_tm(tnet, method="Newman") 

>error: "arguments must have same length"
```

Any ideas? If anyone here has used tnet before, any example would be super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a misunderstanding, but

```
edgelist <- as.matrix("file.csv")
```

does not make sense. `as.matrix` converts an R object to a matrix, it cannot read data from files. I think what you wanted was probably

```
edgelist <- read.csv("file.csv")
```

and then

```
edgelist_in_igraph <- graph.data.frame(edgelist)
```